# unzip file in R after uploading in Shiny server

Tags: r, zip, esri, shiny

I am trying to use Shiny on a local server of ours, to build an app that allows the user to upload a .zip file containing an ESRI shapefile and associated files.  Shiny server's fileInput can obtain the data, and when it does so it sotres it in a temporary directory & filename.  That filename seems to always be a rather generic "0".  If I by hand try to unzip file "0" it works.  But if I try to do it programmatically with the R function unz (which I gather should work) it fails, the error message is that it 'cannot open zip file '0'.  I"m not sure why.  Can anyone help?

here is the code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

mySHPdata <- reactive({
inFile <- input$file1

if (is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)
print((inFile$datapath))

data<-read.table(unz(basename(inFile$datapath), "testme.shp"))
```

One has to extract the relevant files one by one, so here I am just illustrating attempting to
open one of them.  Anyone see why this does not work?

Comment: Are you sure that `basename(inFile$datapath)` is correct? Did you try to use `unz(inFile$datapath, "testme.shp")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't be `basename(inFile$datapath)`, just `inFile$datapath`, or else R doesn't know where to find the `0` file.

Comment: (Sorry, just saw sgibb's comment)

Comment: Thanks - I did try that, and it still did not work.  But I gave up a bit easily, perhaps, as I decided a system call to an external file unzipper would give me more freedom for what I'm trying to do.  And that worked!